# I'm a little unclear how the controller knows to return a JS file rather than HTML (from Railscast #174 Pagination)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In this Railscast #174 Pagination tutorial, the author changes...

```
$(function() {

  $(".pagination a").click(function() { // e.g. a.href = /transactions?page=x
    $.get(this.href, null, null, "script");
    return false;
  });

});
```

When my controller receives this request it returns the JS file (index.js.erb - I added this myself in accordance with the tutorial). I understand that the "script" paramater makes the difference but I can't find out what is happening.

Controller:

```
def index
    # fetch arrays
    @funds = current_user.funds

    # set session vars
    set_filter_date_session_variable(:transactions_filter_date_from) # to db format
    set_filter_date_session_variable(:transactions_filter_date_to) # to db format

    if @fund = current_fund
      @transactions = @fund.transactions
        .where("date >= ? AND date <= ? AND amount < 0", session[:transactions_filter_date_from], session[:transactions_filter_date_to])
        .order("date DESC, id DESC")
      ## perform a paginated query:
      @transactions = @transactions.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    else 
      @transactions = []
    end

    @categories = current_user.categories.order(:name)

    @transactions_filter_date_from = convert_date(session[:transactions_filter_date_from], "%Y-%m-%d", "%d/%m/%Y")
    @transactions_filter_date_to = convert_date(session[:transactions_filter_date_to], "%Y-%m-%d", "%d/%m/%Y")

  end
```

Does the "script" parameter get passed in the request header? Previously I thought the controller looked at the requesting file extension, perhaps default was .html (so if I request *file*.json it knows from the extension that it should return the json view). Could someone please clarify a little, or direct me somewhere I can understand how a controller handles which view to return in this case. I'd like to understand this part fully.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the

```
$.get(this.href, null, null, "script");
```

You're requesting from the serve that it returns the javascript file, hence why the `"script"`
Normally you will notice that at times people include the `format.js` in the controller so that when you put in the url + "." + "format type" (eg. `reports.csv` or `reports.html`) you'd need to include in the controller the code below (you can't just request json if your controller is not setup to bring back that information)

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.html
 format.js
end
```

In your case that you didn't include that format in the controller, the `"script"` in your get function above is asking to respond with the js file. Hence why your js code becomes executed and not your html. If you asked for html, see what happens.

Hope that makes sense?

I deduced to this conclusion because for my pagination I am using jQuery's function `getScript` which looks like this:

```
$.getScript(this.href);
```

Comment: Actually in my controller I didn't write anything new to handle JS format, which is why I was a little unsure how it magically handled it. I don't have `respond_to do |format|` as you can see (I've updated my post). Is this functionality inherited from ActionController::Base?

Comment: Do you have an index.html.erb & index.js.erb file in your views?

Comment: Yes, I have both have an index.html.erb and index.js.erb files